# As part of my template specification, i need to specialize another template

Tags: c++, templates

As part of my RTOSQueue implementation,

```
template<typename T,uint32_t number_of_elements> 
class RTOSQueue : public RTOSQueueBase, public RTOSQueueInterlocutor<T>
{
...
};
```

I need to specialize some helper functions based on the type that's held in the queue:

```
template<typename T>
class RTOSQueueInterlocutor 
{
public:
    void AfterSuccessfulSend(T&message)     {};
    void AfterSuccessfulReceive(T&message)  {};
};
```

The idea is some classes need a little help going in or going out, one of which is a reference counted buffer template:

```
template<typename T, 
#ifdef RTOS_HEADER_INCLUDED
    typename Atomifier=RTOSCriticalSection
#else 
    typename Atomifier=int32_t
#endif    
    >
class shared_buffer : public buffer_interface<T>
{
    T*      m_pPtr;
    size_t  m_uElements;
    int*    count;
...
};
```

(Pardon the Atomifier.  It's there's for thread safety if you're using it with an RTOS)

In order to specialize this, I put this in my code:

```
template<>
void RTOSQueueInterlocutor<shared_buffer<MyBuffer>>::AfterSuccessfulSend(shared_buffer<MyBuffer>&message)
{
    message.increment();
}
```

Then when I declare an RTOSQueue<shared_buffer> it all works fine and the Interlocutor increments the reference count upon a succesful send so it 'stays alive' inside the queue.

I'd LIKE to make this RTOSQueueInterlocutor specialization be "automatic", which would mean whenever I declare a shared_buffer<> object, it should also declare the RTOSQueueInterlocutor<> as well.

Is this possible?  My attempts at putting it in the header file were unsuccesfull.

I tried putting:

```
#ifdef RTOS_HEADER_INCLUDED
template<typename T>
void RTOSQueueInterlocutor<shared_buffer<T>>::AfterSuccessfulSend(shared_buffer<T>&message)
{
    message.increment();
}
#endif
```

Below my definition of shared_buffer<> template, and it didn't like that at all.

Comment: And what exactly did you not like about it?

Comment: @bipll I didn't like that the compiler didn't like it and it wouldn't compile. `error C2244: 'RTOSQueueInterlocutor<shared_buffer<T,RTOSCriticalSection>>::AfterSuccessfulSend': unable to match function definition to an existing declaration` `note: see declaration of 'RTOSQueueInterlocutor<shared_buffer<T,RTOSCriticalSection>>::AfterSuccessfulSend'` `'void RTOSQueueInterlocutor<shared_buffer<T,RTOSCriticalSection>>::AfterSuccessfulSend(shared_buffer<T,RTOSCriticalSection> &)'`